# Cannot open include file :'stddef.h' No such file or directory found error when creating a sample Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, include, include-path

stddef.h file is there in installed Nokia Qt SDK include folder, but still I am getting compile error on running Qt Simulator. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This error message happened with me when I tried to compile for Windows with the VS2008 version of Qt, but Visual C++ 2008 was in fact not installed to my computer. (VS2010 was, but that didn't matter.)

I have the following ideas for you:

- Try installing Visual C++ 2008
  **or**
- Try using MinGW instead of VS2008

The Qt simulator itself is not of much use though, so don't feel bad if you don't manage to make it work. Running your application on the target device itself is the best, and for debugging purposes, you can also compile your stuff for desktop OSes.

Answer (score -4):

Some details to "Try using MinGW instead of VS2008": It is not enough having Visual Studio 2008 Visual C++ (compiler) installed. You'll need the Windows platform SDK too. But there is an easier way to compile a Qt application under Windows: **MinGW**

If having Qt Creator *already installed* (otherwise: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads --> Qt_SDK_Win_online_v1_1_3_en.exe --> custom installation --> Qt SDK / Development Tools / Qt 4.7.4 / **Desktop Qt 4.7.4 - MinGW):

1. Start Qt Creator
2. Menu: Help | Start Updater
3. Package manager (Maintain Qt SDK)
4. In the tree view : Qt SDK / Development Tools / Qt 4.7.4 / **Desktop Qt 4.7.4 - MinGW**

--Harald-René Flasch (aka hfrmobile)

Comment: There's no "Start Updater" menu item in Qt Creator 2.6.2.

Comment: The problem with MSVC is not solved with MinGW. It's just avoiding the problem.