# C++ SDL (Visual Studio 2015): cannot open file stddef.h

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl

I'm relatively new to c++ and have been following the Lazy Foo' tutorial for installing SDL2 in visual studio 2010 (But I am using visual studio 2015).

I have followed the guide a couple of times now, so pretty certain I have incuded the right files etc. Here is a screen shot of my VC++ Directories settings:

[image]

[image: VC++ Directories settings screen shot]

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *window = 0;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        640, 480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Delay(1000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled (32 bit) I receive this error:

> ......\documents\sdl\sdl2-2.0.4\include\sdl_stdinc.h(50): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

I also have the error "cannot open source file stdio.h" when hovering over the include statement for stdio.h

I'm going to continue to look at it all, but if anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated. Failing that I'll probably just install on Linux :)

Cheers and thanks for your time.

Comment: It should be `cstdio.h`. Did you get SDL's Visual Studio development binaries? Or something else?

Comment: @IvanRubinson Thanks, using #include <cstdio> solves the import problem for importing stdio, a much better way of doing it. I'm still getting the error stated above on compilation.

Comment: It's saying it can't find [`<cstddef>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b6eh9x3.aspx); do you have the correct Windows SDK includes referenced?

Comment: like gabe indicates, it's `<cstddef>` for C++ and `<stddef.h>` for C. In the early days using the *.h version occasionally worked, but most compilers I've come across over the last years will complain if you do otherwise.

Comment: @txtechhelp so is it a problem with the header files of SDL 2 that are using the depreciated "#include <stddef.h>" and not "#include <cstddef>"? as the error suggests (include\sdl_stdinc.h(50): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory)

Comment: @IvanRubinson and sorry, yes I downloaded the sdl2 development library (https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip)

Comment: SDL is fine. Including `stddef.h` is the right way to do it in C, in which SDL is written. I'm not sure if wrapping SDL's include in `extern "C"` will help.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303597/cannot-open-include-file-stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory-found-error-when) might help.

Comment: It's not an issue of the wrong header. You can `#include <stddef.h>` in a C++ file, the `<cxxx>` version of the C header files usually wrap the C version in the `std` namespace. The issue is that the file `SDL_stdinc.h` has a `#include <stddef.h>`, which the compiler/VS can't find because the SDK directory that includes the stddef.h file is not being included in your _Include Directories_ (usually a case of the Windows SDK not being installed and referenced properly by VS)

Comment: ah ok thank you @IvanRubinson, as you can tell I'm no C expert :) I believe the problem is to do with visual studio as I am having issues now compiling other simple programs. (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory)

Comment: Thanks @txtechhelp I'm going to reinstall the SDK and see if that solves the problem

Comment: In `additional dependencies` the `SDL2main.lib` should come before `SDL2.lib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions: Use the dropdown, (inherit from parent or project defaults) to repair the visual c++ directories which you shouldn't ever edit.

Don't add it to the c++ directories, That's a weird idea. Add it to Configuration Properties > c/c++ > additional include directories. If you had done that, then you couldn't have possibly messed up the compiler. It's a lot simpler too. Just paste the one directory in there. That's what it's meant for.

Also Lazy Foo seems to only to have a VS2010 guide. Maybe I just couldn't find the VS2015 guide...

Comment: Thank you Zeromus for your time and help, appreciated. I'm currently repairing my installation of visual studio 2015 as I think in the process of including the files as suggested in the tutorial it has messed up something. I agree though about the tutorial, but I think mainly because it is outdated. I've been trying to get SDL installed for a while I've yet to find an up to date installation guide for vs2015.

Comment: Before you reinstall next time, try making a C++ project without SDL that includes the files which can't be found to see whether you've broken the compiler or it's only SDL which can't include them.

Comment: Oddly I can't repro your exact problem though. $(IncludePath) is working as expected in that entry. I mean, it's easy enough to delete the whole entry and get that problem, but it means your $(IncludePath) is wrecked somehow.

Comment: Or you somehow installed visualstudio without the platform SDK or some other critical part. Try customizing it less?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I've repaired visual studio and compilation is working for standard libraries. I have followed your instructions to link to the include folder under Configuration Properties > c/c++ > additional include directories. I still need to link the library directories (x86) and add the additional dependencies of SDL2main.lib and SDL2.lib. Would you recommend following the tutorials guide or would there be a better method? Cheers for your time.

Comment: Linker > Input > add the full path to libs there. My suggestions make it so other people can't build your project without changing the vcxproj settings, if you share the code. You can solve that by sharing SDL with your code and using relative paths from the vcxproj when setting the include directories and library paths.  The concept behind adding to the visual c++ directories instead of what I suggest is that it's like "installing new libraries on your system". That's an awful idea in windows.

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

tends to happen when you're building your program with a version of MSVC different from the one used to build the library.

You should find out which version the SDL binaries were built with, and try using that. A newer MSVC might work, an older one might not.

You can always try building SDL yourself.